# Add apple watch widget / app to capacitor

Tags: ios, apple-watch, capacitor

I have a mobile app published to the mobile using capacitor because the should also be available in browsers for some users / use cases. But now the requirement is to be able to use a little feature using the apple watch without the need to take the mobile / tablet.

Is there a plugin or documentation to do that using capacitor (plugin or so) i am to stupid to find?

What i do NOT expect is to develop the feature using the same technology I guess it is totally clear not to use html/css/typescript. For now only apple need to be supported.

What i do expect: documentation and maybe a lib / package which make it easy to establish communication.

Comment: Found a way / plugin to do it by my own. The way is easier as expected.
Using the apple connectivity plugin you can communicate using the cordova stack.

Comment: Could you provide some detail on how you accomplished it?

Comment: You can do it with the capacitor-widgetbridge-plugin